# Postfix: Send all mailq messages to a single file

Tags: postfix

Wouldn't be nice to create a single file by appending all messages from  mailq.
For instance for a single message you would add

```
postcat -q 91D65348E0EA > listofallmessages
```

then for the next you can say

```
echo "---8<---" >> listofallmessages
postcat -q 45D65348E0EA >> listofallmessages
```

and you can append that way for all the messages in the mailq. This can be done using AWK, but I am not sure if this can be done some more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Well I created a singleliner for this need.

```
mailq | grep  "^[A-F0-9]" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -L1 postcat -q > emails.txt
```

The output is the emails.txt file that can be further analyzed. What it does it creates a list of all messages in a single file emails.txt